# (c#) How can Initialize a generic type with it's type argument object through it's non-generic base class with type safety

Tags: c#, generics, type-safety

I have an ability data factory which has a generic function for creating specific types of abilities. The abilities themselves need to have their own unique AbilityData object passed in which contains both unique and common immutable settings of the ability. The factory contains has the list of this data, which it uses to initialize the abilities upon creation.

My problem is that the solution I have is not type safe. The ability essentially has to validate that the data belongs to it and the factory passes it in. I want to know if there's a type safe way of achieving this, since it feels like a work around solution and maybe a code smell.

```
public class AbilityFactory : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private List<AbilityData> abilityData;

    public IReadOnlyList<AbilityData> AbilityData => abilityData;

    public int AbilityCount => abilityData.Count;

    public Tability CreateAbility<Tability>() where Tability : Ability
    {
        Tability instance = Activator.CreateInstance<Tability>();

        for (int i = 0; i < AbilityData.Count; i++)
        {
            if(instance.MatchAbilityData(AbilityData[i]))
            {
                instance.Initialize(AbilityData[i]);
            }
        }

        return instance;
    }
}
```

```
public abstract class Ability
{
    protected int level;

    public abstract bool MatchAbilityData(AbilityData abilityData);

    public abstract void Initialize<TabilityData>(TabilityData data) where TabilityData : AbilityData;

    public void IncreaseLevel()
    {
        level++;
    }

    public void Update() 
    {        
        OnUpdate();
    }

    protected virtual void OnUpdate()
    {

    }
}

public abstract class Ability<T> : Ability  where T : AbilityData
{
    public T Data { get; private set; }

    public sealed override void Initialize<TabilityData>(TabilityData data)
    {        
        this.Data = data as T;
    }

    public sealed override bool MatchAbilityData(AbilityData abilityData)
    {
        return abilityData is T;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get much value from Ability<T> anyway? Consumers need to cast an Ability to Ability<T> to get at the T Data. Might as well cast the object Data to T.

Comment: I also don't love this sort of protocol API - you need to call a constructor, and then call the initialize method, else things don't work. The factory should know how to initialize this guy, IMO.

Comment: Ability<T> just removes some boilerplate like matching the data to the ability and setting the data I guess. In regards to the factory, I was trying to abide by OCP with the generic creation function. Otherwise, I have to create a new function for every ability I create

Comment: What's the interface that you actually want to support on an ability? What do consumers do with an ability? Give concrete examples, please.

Comment: Consumers should be able to cast the ability and also get the stats of an ability (to display in a UI). They should be able to upgrade the abilities too (increase their level).

Comment: So I imagine that the Ability interface or abstract class would support `void Cast()`, `string GetStats()`, and perhaps `void Level()`. The consumer doesn't care about the ability data therein (T), or the specifics of the ability, does it? Implementations of the ability can do whatever crazy things you want on cast, or on level. What do consumers of the factory know about? The actual type TAbility? Why not just `new TAbility()`, then? Or do they have a string, or enum, and the factory can `switch` on that, and new the concrete class?

Comment: The only consumer who cares about the T used by the ability is the factory, because it's the one who needs initialize it with it. I actually can just new up TAbility, but I still need the initialize method, because I need to use the instance to tell which type of ability data it needs. I probably could just pass in the list of ability data and let it figure it out itself I guess.